# Making label creators in Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a tool in java that can be used to create labels for consumer products. This is similar to CD label creators. What are the techniques available for doing this and guide me in a good direction so that i can walk through perfectly. If you just give me some tips i will start coding on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tutorials that should get you started, using AWT Print and Graphics2D:

- [Swing Tutorial - High-Quality Java Printing](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html)
- [Printing - Java Tutorials by Sun/Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html)

Using the 2D graphics API means you'll be able to render the result on-screen as well as print it.  This will be significantly easier if you already know something about AWT or Swing.